# my single.php do not working anything in wordpress

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

First, my single.php is completely empty.
As an exception there is  in single.php

when I into the single page, the header doesn't work there.
For example, the search function and Real-time notification made by ajax in the header do not work.
Of course, the header works well elsewhere.

also on a single page, the wordpress admin toolbar is not displayed.

This problem is preventing me from putting another code into `single.php`.

Comment: Have you any specific condition in the header for a single page template?

Comment: Can you show us the code in single.php?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that `get_header()` is not in the file. 
Put it at the top of single.php and will output the header, admin bar, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Please put get_header() and get_footer() in that file so header and footer load in that template like others.